# Openerp : new module is not showing into module list

Tags: python, odoo

Basically I have two problems:

1. My newly coded module is not showing into module list , so I am unable to install.
2. I want to debug my module before installation , is there any way through i can do that

Comment: @vinayrks: Tell us what you are doing in detail. This is too cryptic.

Comment: @pyfunc problem 1 : unable to install my newly coded module . that modules are running fine in windows installation but don't with ubuntu installation , In ubuntu that modules are not in showing list of module even after click on 'update module list'

Comment: @pyfunc problem 2 : I want to debug my module before installing it to openerp server , is this possible

Comment: @vinayrks: Provide details on how you have coded to install your module. Are you using distutils? A good way is to edit your question to add the information. The more information means you will get others interested in the problem.

Comment: @vinayrks: When you say debug, I understand you want to unit test it?

Comment: @pyfunc actually I have coded on openobject framework. do you have knowledge in openobject,.....yes my mean is unit testing , sorry i am new in python so not familiar with python jargon

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the module is in addons directory(in linux machine), else check the path of the addons in terminal,

after that update the module list in OpenERP.(update module list will only visible to admin with full access rights.)

then you can see your module in module list, and from form view you can install/un install the module.

to debug the OpenERP module: you have start the server with `--log-level=debug_rpc_answer` parameter.
eg.

```
$ python ./openerp-server --addons ../addons/,../openerp-web/addons --log-level=debug_rpc_answer
```

Answer (score 3):

I am showing this thing for the latest trunk version okz.

If you have developed a new module in addons and if u have added it in the addons folder and than also it is not showing in the module list than first of all restart the server by this.

> ./openerp-server --addons-path=../openobject-addons/,../openerp-web/addons/

than go to the browser and open the

> localhost:8069/web/webclient/home

than login into OpenERP than goto the settingz menu and than to USERS > users
than select ur user and edit it than check the checkbox of **TECHINAL FEATURES** than save it and reload the brower.

Than after reload go to the setting than now in setting > module. U will find three sub menus in the module menu. Itz like this,

> **Modules
>
>    1. Modules
>
>    2. Update Modules List
>
>    3. Apply Scheduled Upgrades**

Than go to the **Update Modules list**  than update it than search ur module and u can find it their.

**HOPE IT WILL BE HELPFULL TO U...


ThankzZZ...**

Answer (score 1):

You should put your module here /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons    unlike commonly misplaced to /usr/share/pyshared/openerp/addons

change ownership:
sudo chown -R root.root usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/module_name

change permissions of the module:
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/module_name -R

restart the server:
sudo service openerp restart

Answer (score 0):

Have you read through the [module development chapter](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/2_4_module_development/index.html) in the documentation? Did you create your module directory under the existing `addons` directory or somewhere else? If you put it somewhere else, then you either have to create a link from the `addons` directory to your module, or zip up your module and import it to the server.

As for testing your module, you can create [test scenarios](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/5_20_unit_testing/index.html) as part of the module. They get executed when you create a database with sample data and then install your module on that database.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable "extended view" for your admin users.

Then, after restarting your instance (necessary so that the new module is seen by the server) you will be able to go to "Preferences -> Modules -> Update module list". After that, you module should appear in the Modules list.

To debug your module, I suggest adding pdb break points in the code which is called by your actions, using e.g.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

This will cause the Python interpreter to go in debug mode when the callback is run.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your module list, go to Installed modules. Remove the **installed** filter from the filter drop down at the top right of the page. Then search for your module name (since normally the number of modules are more than one page)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable extended interface (User --> Preferences --> Interface = Extended)
2. Go to settings --> Modules . (now you will be able to see update Modules list)

Then you'll see modules.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you click 'Installed Modules', and not 'Apps'.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Windows 10:

1. Sign out from Odoo and create a new DB
2. Stop Odoo from the `Services`
3. Start Odoo with `--update=all`option
4. Update Apps List while debug mode enabled.